# Ajax Toolkit ASP.NET (Visual Basic) Not Displaying Calendar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendarextender

I'm trying to use `Ajax Toolkit` in ASP.NET page to display a Calendar Extender with this code, but it's not working for me.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<br />
<br />
<b>Calendar :</b><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Date1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date1">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

It's not displaying the calendar.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date1">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

**Update:**

Do you have the following in your web.config?

```
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="asp" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
```

**Update II**

Put the following at the top of your aspx page.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

Also, you're referencing AjaxControlToolkit.dll, right?  It should be in your bin directory. Right-click project, Add Reference menu choice to add.

Comment: Added web.config contents.  Do you have the above web.config lines?

Comment: I putted those lines, but in the design tab I have this error message :

Unable to display this control because its TagPrefix is not registered in this form.

Comment: Did you put in both register directives?  Phil's is for the calendar, mine is for the toolkit.  Did you undo the <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender changes back to <asp:CalendarExtender?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a `Register` directive to your page for the CalendarExtender?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" TagName="CalendarExtender" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

(Or added it in web.config like Steve suggested)

Have you added an assembly reference to the AjaxControlToolkit dll?

Comment: I putted those lines, but in the design tab I have this error message : Unable to display this control because its TagPrefix is not registered in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is caused by ScriptManager. I have this same issue. The solution is very simple just delete ScriptManager From page or where you placed i.e.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Once you delete scriptmanager then just place ToolkitscriptManager or below code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

You can find this in toolbar -> ajax tab not in Ajax Extensions tab. I hope it will solve your issue